# Is there a way to add google plus reviews to our website?

Tags: google-plus, review

Is there a way to add google plus reviews to our website? Ideally it would be great if there was a way to have the reviews automatically update on our site as they came in.

So far I haven't really found anything. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Maps Places Details Api](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults) response includes up to five reviews. I'm not aware of any other Google APIs that provide access to Place reviews.

```
{
...
"reviews" : [
     {
        "aspects" : [
           {
              "rating" : 3,
              "type" : "quality"
           }
        ],
        "author_name" : "Simon Bengtsson",
        "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/104675092887960962573",
        "language" : "en",
        "rating" : 5,
        "text" : "Just went inside to have a look at Google. Amazing.",
        "time" : 1338440552869
     }
]
...
}
```

Comment: this is not what is being asked.

Comment: i'm confused. I think this is what I'm asking for?

Comment: When you say that it includes up to five reviews, does that mean that it will constantly pull the newest and most recent top 5 reviews every time?? Or is it only any 5 reviews that you choose?

Comment: @ZigMandel I understood the question to mean Place reviews which are the same for Google+ and for Google Maps. This is the only method I'm aware of for getting place reviews.

Comment: @chiccaboom I don't know how Google chooses the five reviews, I'm guessing there is an algorithm that chooses the five that best represent the place.

Comment: plus (google plus) reviews/comments are not place (maps) reviews, i guess o.p. should clarify

Comment: Not sure what reviews you are talking about but [Google+ reviews](https://plus.google.com/105993505145127294133/about) are the same as on Maps.

Comment: ok thanks everyone! I found this google review widget which makes it easier: http://www.netrite.net/sem-tools/google-reviews-widget/

Comment: @abraham edit something so s.o. lets me change votes